# Solrj Block Join Bean support

Tags: solr, solrj

I would like to use a Solrj Bean to save/query nested documents from Solr. Is this possible? I see that since version 4.5 it is possible to use addChildDocument(SolrInputDocument child) but looking at the source code for org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.DocumentObjectBinder I see that nested documents are not taken into consideration. A new annotation additional to the @Field annotation would also be required I guess. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your problem entirely. Yes, I use SolrJ for creation of BlockJoin docs. What's exactly the question?

Comment: I would like to do something like this `ParentObject.java` `@Field List<NestedObject>`

Comment: Then I would like persist the ParentObject in Solr using the addBean method of SolrServer. Is this clearer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to insert nested document as a bean to solr using @Field(child=true) annotation then see below URL:
[SOLRJ-6.0.0: Insertion of a bean object which associate list of bean object is giving null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241489/solrj-6-0-0-insertion-of-a-bean-object-which-associate-list-of-bean-object-is-g)