# SolrJ nested documents

Tags: solr, solrj

I have is this:

```java
public class Product {

    @Field("object_id")
    private String objectId;

    private List<MyObject> listOfMyObjects;

}
```

I use SolrJ to save the info. How can I make `listOfMyObjects` look like list of nested documents in Solr response. I can make the field multivalued, but I need the list to be list of documents.

I can see that this question is asked few times(e.g. [Solrj Block Join Bean support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913752/solrj-block-join-bean-support) ) but no answer. Solr supports nested documents, but how to make it happen using SolrJ with annotations and schema.xml.

Comment: Yeah they are POJO's. They have getters/setters, just left them out for simplicity.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1945 There's a workaround halfway the page that could be helpful. Support for  child docs in DocumentObjectBinder was added as of version 5.1