# How to insert Nested document in solr using spring data solr?

Tags: java, spring, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I need to insert this kind data to solr server.

```
{
    "id":"09123"
    "firstName": "Harshana651175279",
    "lastName": "Samaranayake332146645",
    "department": {
            "id":"001",
            "depName":"dep01"        
        }
}
```

These are the my POJOs for inserting data.

```
public class SolrCustomer {

    @Id
    @Indexed
    private String id;
    @Field
    @Indexed
    private String firstName;
    @Field
    @Indexed
    private String lastName;
    @Field
    private Department department;

    //getters n setters
}

public class Department {

    @Id
    @Indexed
    private String id;
    @Field
    @Indexed
    private String departmentName;

    //getters n setters
}
```

without deparment data its working fine. But can't insert as nested document. When i try it, inserted just like this

```
{
    "firstName": "Harshana651175279",
    "lastName": "Samaranayake332146645",
    "department": [
        "org.ftm.solr.domain.Department@479c1814"
    ],
    "id": "2e204ab3-772d-4af1-a2be-866e21206ecd",
    "_version_": 1536317096485453800
}
```

and this is my schema configured for this.

```
<field name="department" type="strings" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="firstName" type="strings" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="lastName" type="strings" multiValued="false"/>
```

So how can i use these kind of nested document with solr n spring data solr ?

Comment: You cannot use the nested documents in SOLR. It needs to fatten before you push the document into SOLR. 
For Reference : [https://qnalist.com/questions/4775755/how-to-write-nested-schema-xml-in-solr](https://qnalist.com/questions/4775755/how-to-write-nested-schema-xml-in-solr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can insert nested document, Check the answer of below question:
[SOLRJ-6.0.0: Insertion of a bean object which associate list of bean object is giving null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241489/solrj-6-0-0-insertion-of-a-bean-object-which-associate-list-of-bean-object-is-g/37243756#37243756)